# Offline gem dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Unfortunately, when I am at work I am developing on a network that can in no way be connected to the internet. So I have been downloading each gem I need individually from rubygems.org and then copying them via flashdisk to the internal network. This works fine except when I need a gem that has other gem dependencies I have to individually download these and it is slow and tedious.

Is there a way to download a gem and all of it's dependent gems for an offline install? I do have a computer on the internet that I can do gem installs from and I was hoping I could download the gems I need and it would automatically install the dependencies, and then I could copy across to the internal network. But `gem install` does not seem to leave a .gem file behind once it is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) tool, especially `bundle package` could be useful for your use case.