# buildr offline installation

Tags: java, rubygems, buildr

I have offline PC with any Internet access (inside private intranet), and I need set to buildr on this box.

***Is it possible to make buildr installation on machine without access to the Internet?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You will need to collect the gems Buildr depends and all their dependencies, then download them from rubygems.org. You will then be able to install buildr by typing:

```
gem install buildr-1.4.7.gem
```

Here is a complete answer for an other gem, rails, the last answer seems to be on spot:

[Offline gem dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357895/offline-gem-dependencies)

```
gem fetch rails -y -t /path/to/flash_drive
```

Comment: The http://rubygems.org/gems/buildr will also show a list of all the gem dependencies